# JQuery change the button class where value = myValue on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML code

```
 <input type="button" class="green red" value="Open"/>
    <input type="button" class="red yellow" value="Close"/>
    <input type="button" class="orange  red" value="Close"/>
  <input type="button" class="blue  red black" value="Close"/>
```

I want to change the style class of the the buttons using the JQuery while loading the page.

requirement: style class **red**  should be replaced with **green** for  the buttons which have value **"Close"**.

**Note:** I cant change the above code because it is auto generated.

Could you please let me know how to change the styles while loading the page using JQuery/Java Script

Comment: $('input.red:button[value="Close"]').removeClass('red').addClass('green')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('input.red:button[value="Close"]').removeClass('red').addClass('green')
})
```

Comment: Actually he says "while loading the page".